# If P(Q)R and Q(R)S, prove P(Q)S

Tags: geometry

> $$\text{If }\ P(Q)R\ \text{ and }\ Q(R)S,\; prove\ P(Q)S$$
>
> Axioms:
>
> - (i) If P(Q)R, then R(Q)P
> - (ii) If P(Q)R, then $\sim$(P(R)Q) and P $\neq$ Q
> - (iii) There are at least two distinct points
> - (iv) For any two points P and Q, there is a point R such that P(Q)R

This is what I have:

Proof: If P(Q)R and Q(R)S, let P, Q, R be any point and let P(Q)R by axiom (ii) P$\neq$Q. LetQ=R, from this and given P(Q)R, we can get P(R)Q. However, this is a contradiction by axiom (ii) so, Q$\neq$P. Same goes from Q(R)S. Therefore, P(Q)R , Q(R)S and P(Q)S.

How do I fix it to make it correct?

Comment: I have a question about notation $A(B)C$ (that should be better written as a **ternary** relationship a(A,B,C)). I understand that you are trying to derive the conclusion in a formal way, but the goal you try to achieve has surely an interpretation ; my own one is that we are working on a kind of geometry on a "one dimensional space" and a model for $A(B)C$ : is "$A,B,C$, not necessary all distinct, are aligned in this order." or "$B$ is in between $A$ and $C$". Is my guess correct ?

Comment: Could you give the origin of this exercise ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me exhibit a model of the system of axioms where the looked-for property :

$$P(Q)R \ \& \ Q(R)S \ \ \implies \ \ P(Q)S\tag{1}$$

isn't valid. It suffices :

- to take as "universe" the set of natural integers $\mathbb{N}$
- and to take relationship $A(B)C$ to be "$B$ is the midpoint of $A$ and $C$" with $A,B,C$ all distinct.

All the axioms are verified but (1) isn't valid.

Here is a counterexample with $p=0, q=1, r=2, s=3$ ;  indeed:

- $q=1$ is the midpoint of $p=0$ and $r=2$ and
- $r=2$ is the midpoint of $q=1$ and $s=3$,

but $q=1$ isn't the midpoint of $p=0$ and $s=3$.

For another view on 'betweenness" : https://services.math.duke.edu/~wka/math123S/between.pdf . See also the recent question [Given axioms, how do we know it defines a geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3153173)